Не открывается javascript файл
Хотел в браузере firefox отключить pocket, нужный файл не открывается.
https://imgur.com/a/YT2ouwJ (Скриншот ошибки)

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Чтобы отключить Pocket достаточно перейти в about:config, далее написать в поиск extensions.pocket.enabled и изменить значение на false

@ΝNL993 Спасибо!
